# At a birthday party 7 boys and 3 girls are in a row. How many different arrangements are possible if there are no boys between any two girls?

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt:
I counted the girls as one unit because boy can't be between them and now I technically have 8 seats.
I did 8! as the arrangements and multiplied by 3! because the girls can arrange among themselves.

My final answer was 8! * 3! (the answer format is _! * _!) but I got it wrong

Comment: Looks correct.  Did you try $3!\times 8!$?

Comment: Was just about to say that. But I think it's silly that an automated system would not permit that. If it only permits one answer it should have just permitted evaluating it as $241920$.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @BrianTung.  In fact, I will go further.  It is not reasonable, in this day and age, to expect an automated system to accept an expression such as either $3! \times 8!$ or $8! \times 3!$.  You can't really expect this type of sophisticated Machine Learning in a (tax dollar driven) educational system (as opposed to a *for-profit* Corporation).